# Is it possible to install without a CD or USB drive?

Tags: system-installation

I've got a friend who wants to try Ubuntu on his netbook, but doesn't have a USB drive he can use, and of course the netbook doesn't have a CD drive. Is it possible for him to install Ubuntu?