# Install Ubuntu Netbook 10.10 without CD/USB/WUBI from HDD on WinXP

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, wubi, installation

I have downloded the Ubuntu Netbook 10.10 ISO file. When I mount it on a Virtual drive it gives me the option to install it via CD(restart and boot from disc) or use the WUBI installer. The [WUBI installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29) warns about poor disc performance. There is a way to convert the WUBI installed Ubuntu into a dedicated partition Ubuntu installation via [LVPM](http://lubi.sourceforge.net/lvpm.html). The [Official Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) links to a how-to for 7.04/7.10/8.10, whereas the [forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=438591) says

> LVPM currently does not work with
>   installs generated by Wubi 10.04
>   (patches welcome).

So the status about 10.10 is unknown. Plus even if LVPM does work, it has the problem of [wiping the partition](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=438591) on which it is going to be installed.

Is there a way to install Ubuntu without using a USB/CD? yes -> WUBI

Is there a way to install a *normal* Ubuntu installation using WUBI? yes -> LVPM

But LVPM needs a clean partition.

Can I install Ubuntu into an existing logical partition without having to lose or move my files in advance to another partition with or without the WUBI method?

(My Netbook:
Primary Partition(40GB): WinXP Home(Free Space 3GB)
Logical Partition(100GB): Data(Free Space ~10GB)
)

**I have seen some programs like Norton Ghost, Partition Magic etc. boot into a different environment to format or restore hdds from WinXP(after restarting). Can't a installer do something similar and boot into a Ubuntu installer environment?**

I have been through this [Is it possible to install without a CD or USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-without-a-cd-or-usb-drive)

(I had asked this question on https://superuser.com/questions/215661/install-ubuntu-netbook-10-10-without-cd-usb-wubi-from-hdd-on-winxp  but since this looks like a better place I am posting it here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not currently possible to migrate a Wubi installation to a dedicated partition.

In order to do a full installation of Ubuntu that isn't reliant on your Windows partition to operate, you will need to use a CD, USB disk, or PXE boot from another computer containing the live media.

We are working on fixing this, but it is a longer-term goal of Wubi and will likely not make the 10.10 release.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not obsessed by LVPM I can suggest you a different solution :)

Do you know about http://www.netboot.me/ ? You should.

It is a site that host a service to do Network Boot and Installation of the most famous GNU/Linux distribution.

According to http://www.netboot.me/gettingstarted this instruction you can use it in the mode you prefer.

Also if the distribution you're looking for isn't supported yet you can add yourself. Quoting from the site:

> **My favorite tool or distro isn't supported!**
>
> It can be! You can create your own configuration (a Google account is required for login). If you think the config will be of general interest, file a bug to have it included in the boot menu.

So, in your case I would use the *Booting using tftp.netboot.me* as long as you have access to the internet ( by an ethernet cable would be best, but also your wifi card may be supported :D )

Answer (score 1):

I think you messed up the whole computer, you should DO a CLEAR INSTALL!!
See this: [Installation without a CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Installation%20without%20a%20CD), and I can say this: [Network installion](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Server%20and%20network%20installations). These methods are very hard for beginners, but if you can *read*, you can do everything, what you want... :)