# How to install Ubuntu on XP then uninstall XP?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am living in Lebanon where it is rare to find an Ubuntu CD to buy, let alone find someone capable of installing it.

I want to download Ubuntu and install it by myself, but I don't want to dual boot because I don't have a powerful computer.  I have used Ubuntu on my VPS, but never on desktop before. I would like to know if Ubuntu can be downloaded and installed on an XP Pro then remove XP Pro.

Can anyone guide me through the process?

Comment: You realize that Ubuntu can be installed from a Live CD, without having to boot in Windows at all?

Comment: There is a way to convert the WUBI installed Ubuntu into a dedicated partition Ubuntu installation via LVPM. However you might want to look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/15327/install-ubuntu-netbook-10-10-without-cd-usb-wubi-from-hdd-on-winxp/15332#15332

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all use the live CD to boot into an UBUNTU live session (do not install). Then you can save all your music and ebooks as you can access the windows partition. If you now want to install UBUNTU you can choose to use the whole disk for the install thus windows will be deleted and UBUNTU installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, if you dont have access to another machine.

1. Reinstall any OS
2. Download and burn Ubuntu
3. Install Ubuntu from the Cd, while doing this format the drives.

I also believe afaik they still mail copies of Ubuntu if you ask for them, I am not sure if they will ship to Lebanon though.