# Upgrade without internet & CD

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install without a CD or USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915/is-it-possible-to-install-without-a-cd-or-usb-drive)

I have an Acer Aspire One D255E netbook. Both 10.04 and 10.10 hangs on install from USB, so could not install them. However Ubuntu 9.10 worked and installed.

Then I figured I would just connect to the internet and update. However, the internet does not work (doesn't show up in notification), but it worked when 10.04 and 10.10 where used as a live USB. Is there a way to update by using the 10.04-desktop ISO file from a USB or somewhere in 9.10, say the documents folder?