# Is it possible to install without a Live CD?

Tags: re-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install without a CD or USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915/is-it-possible-to-install-without-a-cd-or-usb-drive)

I am wondering if it is possible to install Ubuntu without the use of a Live CD. I have an issue so I wish to reinstall it now, but I currently do not have any cd's at home.