# The installer needs to commit changes to partition, but cannot do so because partitions on the following could not be unmounted. /isodevice

Tags: 11.04, installation

The installer needs to commit changes to partition tables, but cannot do so because partitions on the following could not be unmounted. /isodevice

I'm installing this from a external 1TB hard drive there is no internal hard drive ...it crashed so I'm trying to install this via Usb hard drive and i keep getting this error

Ubuntu 11.04 i believe 
Hp Touch smart tm2 no disk drive

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu from a USB drive to the same USB drive?

Comment: Yes its a 1TB USB hard drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (easily) install Ubuntu to the drive you are booting from.

The best choice here would be create another installation USB drive with an USB pen or something similar and use that pen to boot installing the system to the USB 1Tb drive.

For more information about how to do so please visit the following links

- [Is it possible to install without a Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53276/is-it-possible-to-install-without-a-live-cd)

Comment: I hope someone says otherwise and you get another answer, else this is the only thing you can do :S I am clearing the comments above for now. Regards

Comment: This fixed my problem thanx!

Answer (score 1):

simply unmount isodevice

> sudo umount -l -r -f /isodevice

and restart the installer