# Unable to install from CD or USB drive

Tags: installation, 12.04, live-cd, usb-drive

Ubuntu installer in some place shows that one of the files is corrupted or something. After picking the "Retry" option it continues, and at the end of installation it shows `Unable to install Ubuntu`.

I've tried both a USB drive and a CD, but the result was the same.

Is there any easy to install version of Ubuntu, which can just connect the Internet and download missing/corrupted/damaged/etc.files instead of failing installation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to install without a CD or USB drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/915/is-it-possible-to-install-without-a-cd-or-usb-drive)

Answer (score 1):

There used to be; it was called the mini installer I think. It did basically what you said - a 20MB iso which got some basic settings and downloaded the rest from a mirror.  Unfortunately after looking through both cdimage.ubuntu.com and releases.ubuntu.com it looks like they've dropped support. I'd try downloading another copy of the iso.

EDIT: Just thought; if you have another PC available, you could try [network booting the installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot), and that will allow you to download everything from a mirror.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. But if a file is corrupted, just redownload Ubuntu and put the new one onto your USB. Often a corrupted file just means something went a bit wrong when you either downloaded or copied the file.

Comment: Yup, but I used two copies of iso. One on CD was downloaded some time ago, and another one today a while before installing.