# Downloading takes hours:

Tags: 12.04

I have downloaded "ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso" and extracted it using magic ISO. There is a file wubi.exe is the extracted folder. To install ubuntu i double clicked it ( i am using windows 7); it asks the isntallaton folder and asks to create username and password. Then straight away it says it is downloading "ubuntu-12.04.1-wubi-i386.tar.xz". It it shows nearly seven hours of downloading time remaining (i have a slow internet connection). Can't i install ubuntu offline?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the iso (you didn't have to, the wubi.exe installer [can be downloaded independently](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)), there is no need to download the installation package again.

Just place the iso image in the same folder where the wubi.exe file is; start wubi.exe -- it should detect the iso file and run the installation offline. More on that [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_use_a_manually_downloaded_ISO.3F).

Alternatively, you can use the iso to install Ubuntu on a separate partition.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I placed wubi.exe in the folder that contained the iso file. Then the installation completed. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a full install you will need to burn the iso to a CD and start your computer from it. Check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

If you don't have a CD avaliable, check: [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick) or [Is it possible to install without a CD or USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915/is-it-possible-to-install-without-a-cd-or-usb-drive)

Comment: No need to do that. If he wants to use WUBI, the WUBI can use the ISO image for installation, am I wrong?

Comment: I don't know, Wubi was always quite unreliable for me. If he really wants to use Wubi he can, but if he doesn't know what wubi is, quite likely, a full install will be a better experience.

Comment: I completely agree (OK, so I don't know about reliability, because I never used Windows outside of a Vbox); on the other hand, it is easier to break Windows with a botched attempt to install Ubuntu side by side, and that can be one hell of a bad experience.