# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on my Windows 8 computer without any CD or USB drive?

Tags: system-installation, uefi, windows-8, 64-bit

## *Please read entire post CAREFULLY before answering.*

*This question will make you confused if you don't.*

#### Information (May skip :P)

- OS : Windows NT 6.2 (Windows 8 K)
- Equipped hard disk

  - Total 1TB, 1 disk
  - C: (Simple Layout, NTFS, Boot, Pagefile, Crash dump, Main): total 488,039,776,256 bytes, used 93,473,599,488 bytes
  - D: (Simple Layout, NTFS, Main): total 486,859,075,584 bytes, used 8,426,016,768 bytes
  - hidden: Ask if needed
- Brand(manufacturer): Samsung Electronics
- Processor(CPU): Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz
- RAM: 8GB , 64-bit , OS 64-bit

#### Question (READ THEM ALL VERY CAREFULLY)

- Is there any way to install Ubuntu on this computer **without any external disk (CD, USB drive, etc)**
- Note : This computer is 64-bit, so *[this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915/is-it-possible-to-install-without-a-cd-or-usb-drive) did not help me.*
- WUBI does not support **UEFI**, and This computer **uses** it.
- *No Virtual PC programs like VirtualBox or VMWare*, because it takes memory.

**EDIT** : I already found a USB drive in my home, so now it is installed on my computer xD

Comment: You could install VirtualBox in windows, then Ubuntu inside of that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 ways to install Ubuntu *as dual boot* on a machine already running windows.

1. Use a CD. You can't/won't do it.
2. Use a USB drive. You can't/won't do it.
3. Use the .iso file in a virtual machine *as a means to avoid CD/USB* such that it also boots alongside Windows. You claim you can't/won't do it.
4. WUBI. Not compatible with UEFI.

Sorry, but you're stuck. It may be possible to do something *really* cunning using Windows ext2 drivers, an iso image extractor and a lot of both Linux and Window know how, but if you could do that you wouldn't need to ask questions here.

I've already provided an answer for machine that have no CD and won't boot from USB. If that's not the solution then you've not communicated your question properly.

Comment: Thanks for the question, and I'm so glad you SUCCEDED reading my question!

Answer (score 6):

Do your repartitioning from Windows, it will not let you do any damage to the Windows OS this way. Leave the partitions where you'll install Linux unformatted, I assume you'll want to use ext4 and swap on them, and reserve a small partition, maybe 1GB, for the Linux installation media, that you can format to FAT32; copy the content from your installation ISO (not the ISO file itself) to this partition; add an entry to this partition to the Windows boot loader with [EasyBCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyBCD), you can find how on the Internet, such as in [this article](http://apcmag.com/how-to-dual-boot-windows-8-and-linux.htm). Note the order of your partitions so you'll remember which one you'll format and install on it, then restart and boot into the Linux live session from the install partition and perform normal installation. The installer will recognize the existing EFI system partition and will copy a boot entry there, but you can add another entry for your installed Linux to the Windows BCD the same way you added for the install partition.

Comment: Can I trust this?

Comment: @jinoh67 There's plenty of room for cock-up here! Overwriting a partition, or corrupting a file system could happen so easily. But, that's true for *any* install system, even a LiveCD.

Comment: @ams I found a USB drive in my home, so now I already installed it!

Comment: @ams I just marked it as accepted, but as you can see it uses EasyBCD which isn't compatible with UEFI.

Comment: == This solution works only for MBR. UEFI not supported. ==

Comment: Hi, did you try booting from such a partition? Some firmwares are permissive enough to enumerate all FAT32 partitions which contain a valid UEFI folder structure and let you choose one to boot from, when you disable secure booting, though most of them are rather restrictive and wouldn't go further than the first EFI system partition.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to a screw-driver and another computer?

Windows must be installed on the same machine that it will run on, but Linux is less fussy. :)

When I've been in this position before I've removed the hard drive from the problem computer and attached it to another computer. (I used a cheap external USB drive enclosure, but you could install it directly into the other computer.)

I'd then install the new OS onto the drive using CD/USB. (Actually, I did it in a Qemu/KVM VM booted from the .iso image, but that was just showing off.)

Finally, I moved the drive back to its real home and it should Just Work. You might have trouble with UEFI though (maybe you can disable secure boot in the settings)?

Comment: I said "Install without CD or DVD", and it is NOT about UEFI problem. Please read all before reading, as I said on the top of the article.

Comment: I did read you whole question and you're asking to do the impossible. I therefore presumed you have a problem with your CD/USB on that machine. I didn't say you had a problem with UEFI now; I said you might later. Please read the whole answer.

Comment: Okay I see it now. Oh no, my laptop doesn't have any CD drive, my USB HDD cable is broken, WUBI not working.... :(