# How to install Ubuntu 13.04 without a CD or USB?

Tags: installation, 13.04

Is it possible to install Ubuntu Raring Ringtail 13.04 without CD or USB?

Comment: What equipment are you using and what options do you have? Do you have internet connectivity or network access? If so download the package on to the server and install from there.

Comment: For Ubuntu 12.04 and before see http://askubuntu.com/q/915/62483

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to install Ubuntu on your machine and you have already ruled out using wubi to install ubuntu inside windows; then I think the following method should work:

1. Remove your hard disk.
2. Connect it to a machine which does have a USB drive or CD ROM.
3. Install Ubuntu on your hard drive.
4. Re-attach the hard drive to your machine.

I know this does not answer the question of "how to install ubuntu without USB or CD ROM", but it can help some one without a USB and CD ROM get ubuntu nevertheless.